# In what logical sense is Haskell referentially transparent?

Tags: haskell

Haskell is sometimes said to "replace equals for equals".  The following code shows this isn't true under every interpretation of such a sentence.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) follows that by saying `f(x)=f(x)` for every `x` but that doesn't seem to carry any actual logical content one can test, it would be true by the reflexive law, a tautology.

I think the phrasing needed to make a logical claim like this is more like Leibniz' law (or indistinguishable identicals) where 
`x=y` implies for every `f`, `f(x)=f(y)`.  That claim fails in the illustration below within Haskell.  (We override `==` to make a partition type, but our function definition can freely ignore this and do.)

My question is, can one actually state referential transparency in a way that can be logically tested, and does Haskell actually uphold that logical claim?

```hs
module Main (main) where

data Floop = One | Two | Three
instance Eq Floop where
    One == One         = True
    One == Two         = False
    One == Three       = False
    Two == One         = False
    Two == Two         = True
    Two == Three       = True   --- 2=3
    Three == One       = False
    Three == Two       = True   --- 3=2
    Three == Three     = True

shuffle       :: Floop -> Floop
shuffle One   = Two
shuffle Two   = Two    --- fix 2
shuffle Three = One    --- move 3

main = print ( (Two == Three) && (shuffle Two /= shuffle Three) )
--- prints "True" proving Haskell violates Leibniz Law
```

Comment: You haven't violated referential transparency there, you've just made a pathological `Eq` instance. Sure, the language doesn't forbid you from doing this, but nor does it forbid you from making unlawful `Functor` or `Monad` instances. If you apply a function to values which are *actually the same* as opposed to *decreed to be the same by some weird rule I made up*, then the output values are indeed guaranteed to be the same. In short, `(==)` in Haskell doesn't have to actually mean "the same" (although to be a sensible instance, it should).

Comment: @RobinZigmond you should post this as an answer, and specially clarify that `(==)` is not magic, but just a function.

Comment: To clarify, this example is a "weird rule" so as to make it short. But real data types I use often need to override == to be defined properly, but this opens the door to functions ignoring this -- often with very subtle seemingly natural intentions.  `==` ain't magic but it is a primitive notion with documented intentions of equality and once set, it is the equality your type has.  So seems a thin answer to me.

Comment: To restate what Robin Zigmond said: the notion of referential equality is about mathematical equality, and _not_ about any Haskell function, even if it happens to have a similar-sounding name.

Comment: OK, so the correct statement is that Haskell is guaranteed to be referentially transparent with respect to "ordinary equality". Any custom `Eq` instances you make will only give "referentially transparency" with respect to functions that you yourself ensure respect that.

Comment: So I think the phrase should be "judgmental equality", in particular a type class for modular integers Z/nZ would have a "mathematical equality" upon which Haskell wouldn't be referentially transparent.  So its RT is only for a subset of types.  That is much weaker than "replacing equals for equals".

Comment: No, it's exactly "replacing equals for equals". You just have to realise that "equals" here is meant literally, not in the sense of an arbitrary implementation of `Eq` in Haskell (which can in theory be completely arbitrary). And you can certainly define integers modulo a particular `n` as a Haskell type if you want to - but if you want to do so by making a `newtype` for `Int` with a custom `Eq` instance, it's up to you to make sure any functions you define on this type are well defined, aka referentially transparent.

Comment: Well we can't have it both ways.  If a type definition depends on an equivalence rel. (some do) then terms of this type are equal exactly when that eq. rel. says so (by defn.). So on such types Haskell isn't RT, as everyone seems to confirm here.  I think this is enough to clarify my question so I'll close.  It isn't my intent to provoke argument over jargon, but this thread seems to confirm that Haskell views RT as something weaker than the logical statement that symbols x==y imply f(x)==f(y). Either one disavows some == or one disavows some types (partition types) as domains. Thx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding slightly on what I already said in my comment (thanks @FyodorSolkin for the prod):

You haven't violated referential transparency there, you've just made a pathological `Eq` instance.

While, as you've observed, the language doesn't forbid you from doing this, nor does it forbid one from making unlawful `Functor` or `Monad` instances. (Because it would be totally unfeasible to try to check these laws in practice.) But just because something doesn't cause a compiler error doesn't necessarily mean it's the right thing to do.

So the problem with your example is that while, semantically, `(==)` in Haskell indeed means "equal", it's just a function, in fact a method of a typeclass - which you can therefore implement however you want. Nothing stops me from defining, for example:

```
instance (Eq) (a -> b) where
    _ == _ = True
```

and suddenly all functions will be considered "equal" under this definition. Clearly referential transparency will be violated if we consider this to be a true definition of equality. My point is that it's not. In fact it's quite obvious what "equality" means for any type which isn't either a function or otherwise depends on or "contains" function types. (It's actually obvious what equality of functions should mean too, it's just impossible for there to be a general algorithm to determine if two arbitrary functions are equal.)

[EDIT: I just remembered it also doesn't make much sense to talk about equality of `IO` actions. There might be some other abstract types like that where there's no clear definition of what equality would mean.]

To stray into abstract mathematics for a minute: your `Eq` instance certainly defines an equivalence relation, which is considered to be a sort of "generalised equality" - and indeed is equality if you use the relation to make equivalence classes. But then it's nonsense to try to apply a function to such a domain/type which differs on different elements of the same equivalence class. Such a thing - as in your example - actually fundamentally fails to be a well-defined mathematical function, because you're defining it on the individual elements in a way which fails to respect the equivalence relation.

Comment: I don't think this gets at the question.  While == is a function it plays a fixed role in the language, once overridden, it is == my type has.  I think the line "fails to be a well-defined mathematical function" says exactly my concern.   Well-defined means exactly that x=y implies f(x)=f(y).  If that isn't what is meant by referential transparency then what is?

Comment: I don't think it is "generalized equality" at all.  Some types are only defined by the added equivalence, e.g. integers modulo n.  With this interpretation RT doesn't hold on all types.  But my actual question: is it that you agree x=y -> f(x)=f(y) is what is truly meant by RT (even though only true in limited interpretations)?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely what it means. As far as I understand it, RT is a programming term rather than a mathematical one - in mathematics all functions are RT because that's basically the definition, in programming it isn't true in most languages (due to things like implicit state, I/O, and so on). Btw I don't see how the integers modulo n argue against my characterisation of equivalence relations as "generalised equality" - it's obviously a canonical example, and the whole point of it is to say that "we consider all integers that differ by a multiple of n to be the same".

Comment: I found RT in logic/philosophy back to Frege so it predates programming, but I'm attempting to understand how faithfully the term is used in programming. The distinction of equals vs. eq. rel. is that the latter is on the original type, the former is on the associated partition -- the new type.

Answer (score 6):

> `f(x)=f(x)` for every x

is by no means a tautology. In many popular languages, this property does not hold. Consider Java, for instance:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Transparency {
  static int f(List<Object> xs) {
    xs.add(xs.size());
    return xs.size();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> x = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Is java referentially transparent? " + (f(x) == f(x)));
  }
}

$ javac Transparency.java
$ java Transparency 
Is java referentially transparent? false
```

Here, because `f` mutates its input `x`, it would change behavior if we substitute x's definition into `f(x) == f(x)`: `f(new ArrayList<>()) == f(new ArrayList<>())` is in fact true, but when using a variable to reduce duplication it evaluates to false. In Haskell, such a substitution is always valid (disregarding cheats like `unsafePerformIO`).

Comment: Tautology in the sense I was using is to say that writing `f(x)=f(x)` when `=` is an equivalence relation doesn't communicate anything you meaningfully test because one law of `=` is that `whatever=whatever`.  If however you have different symbols on each side then there is a question that can be tested, i.e. `x=y` implies `f(x)=f(y)` may or may not be true.